# Apache POI: Rerender Chart in PowerPoint - Embedded Excel Sheet

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint Template that I process via apache.poi (vers. 3.14).
I need to change the embedded excel data, that serves as a dataprovider for a chart. I am as far as that the data in the excel file is changed (visible when I click on the chart and view the underlying data) - only the chart does not update. I cant find an option how to provide the chart with new data or tell chart to rerender!

```
XSLFChart chart = (XSLFChart) rel;
CTChart ctChart = chart.getCTChart();

POIXMLDocumentPart xlsPart = chart.getRelations().get(0);
XSSFWorkbook wb1 = null;

if (chart.getRelations().get(0).getPackagePart().getContentType().contains("spreadsheet")) {
wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(chart.getRelations().get(0).getPackagePart().getInputStream()); 
wb1.getSheetAt(0).getRow(2).getCell(1).setCellValue(666666);

OutputStream xlsOut = xlsPart.getPackagePart().getOutputStream();
try {
     wb1.write(xlsOut);
} finally {
     wb1.close();
     xlsOut.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: did you get around this problem? I am using similar code, the chart is not rendered for me either but as soon as I right click on plot area and do edit data, the chart appears. Weird, there must be something that needs to be done to get the chart refreshed based on the data saved in embedded excel.

Comment: charts are not really supported in apache poi ...